# XML Serialization with optional segment

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a problem when i want to serialize below to XML because segment E1WPU03 is optional but when it has a value then I need to put it under segment E1WPU02

I've been try for two days but it end up it writes segmen E1WPU02 first then segment E1WPU03 which doesn't work

How can I do this?

[image: correct XML]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` doesn't normally interleave elements. You can trick it, however, with a `List<>` and multiple `[XmlElement(...)]` specifying a type:

```
class Program
{  
    static void Main()
    {
        var root = new MyXmlRoot
        {
            Items = {
                new Bar { },
                new Blap { },
                new Bar { },
            }
        };
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyXmlRoot));
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, root);
    }
}

public abstract class Foo { } // base type used for the list
public class Bar : Foo {
    // more props here
}
public class Blap : Foo {
    // more props here
}
public class MyXmlRoot
{
    private readonly List<Foo> items = new List<Foo>();
    [XmlElement("E1WPUO2", typeof(Bar))]
    [XmlElement("E1WPUO3", typeof(Blap))]
    public List<Foo> Items { get { return items; } }
}
```

Other elements like `E1WPU01` do not need to go in `Items` if there is no need to interleave them - they can go directly on `MyXmlRoot` (as you probably already have).